# Inserting a foreach output in a horizontal HTML table

Tags: php, html, arrays, xml

I'm a newbie who's been looking for a solution regarding inserting a PHP `foreach` output in a horizontal **HTML** table. In the **Dataset** `.xml` file, there are multiple Series and each has 24 x `TIME_PERIOD`'s and 24 x `OBS_VALUE`'s as attributes.

My problem is that all of them are being listed vertically (naturally) by the code I wrote below and I do not know how to divide them horizontally. I'd be glad if you could help me create a horizontal table for each Series.

Consider this screenshot of the current output:

[image]

**Code snippet:**

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("00750006.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");                                                           

foreach($xml->DataSet->Series as $series) {

   foreach($series->Obs as $obs) {

           $tp = (string)$obs["TIME_PERIOD"];
           $val = (string)$obs["OBS_VALUE"];

           echo "<table><tr>

           <td class='dataC'>$tp</td>
           <td class='dataC'>$val</td>

                </tr></table>";
   } 
}
```

Comment: please clarify question more...! can you please write how your table looks like ?

Comment: Hey. Just edited and added the screenshot.

Comment: please do you want this ?

1953 | 1954 | 1955 .....(row 1)
168886 | 154227 | 164857 .........(row 2)
??

Comment: Like this http://imgur.com/L9Zkglv

Comment: @miraak check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating table for each row. Which is wrong here. try this. then assign style to display it horizontal

```
<?php 
$xml=simplexml_load_file("00750006.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");                                                           

foreach($xml->DataSet->Series as $series) {
  echo "<table class='series-tbl'>";
   foreach($series->Obs as $obs) {

           $tp = (string)$obs["TIME_PERIOD"];
           $val = (string)$obs["OBS_VALUE"];

           echo "<tr>

           <td class='dataC'>$tp</td>
           <td class='dataC'>$val</td>

                </tr>";
   } 
   echo "</table>";
}
?>
<style type="text/css">
  .series-tbl
  {
    float: left;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: @miraak If this answer is help full then please up-vote and accept the answer

Comment: I'm tryin, however "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("00750006.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");                                                           
$tmp = array();
foreach($xml->DataSet->Series as $series) {
   foreach($series->Obs as $key=>$obs) {
           $tp = (string)$obs["TIME_PERIOD"];
           $val = (string)$obs["OBS_VALUE"];

           $tmp[$key] .= "<td class='dataC'>$tp</td>
           <td class='dataC'>$val</td>";
   }
}
foreach($tmp as $row){
    echo "<table><tr>";
    echo $row;
    echo "</tr></table>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just you have to add row, While inserting new line, So remove your `<table>` tag from nested loop. then it will create seperate tables.

```
<?php 
$xml=simplexml_load_file("00750006.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");                                                           

foreach($xml->DataSet->Series as $series) {

echo "<table style='float: left;'>";
foreach($series->Obs as $obs) {

       $tp = (string)$obs["TIME_PERIOD"];
       $val = (string)$obs["OBS_VALUE"];

       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td class='dataC'>$tp</td>";
       echo "<td class='dataC'>$val</td>";
       echo "</tr>";
 } 
 echo "</table>";
}
?>
```